# pm2 install problem// zsh: permission denied: pm2 //and// npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher

Tags: node.js, pm2

please help me
im using mac m1. PM2 is failing to install.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.
-> to solve about this problem, i tried to install higher uuid version. but its not work (same warning message displayed.)

so i ignored that warning and tried to check the version of PM2, and it said like that.
-> zsh: permission denied: pm2

-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install uuid@7.0.3 -g

added 1 package in 269ms
-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

changed 185 packages in 1s

12 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
-MacBookPro ~ % pm2 --version
zsh: permission denied: pm2

//from here, it's all the similar error//

-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npx uuid@7.0.3
Need to install the following packages:
uuid@7.0.3
Ok to proceed? (y) y
3dc60520-4f29-444b-b866-9caddade78f8
-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install -g pm2
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install uuid@8.3.2 --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

-MacBookPro ~ % sudo npm install uuid@latest

added 1 package in 188ms
-MacBookPro ~ % pm2 --version
zsh: permission denied: pm2

Comment: Why are you using sudo to install?

Comment: i got an error when i didn't use 'sudo'. uuid is same. 
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open